# The way to change CSS themes in React application?

Tags: css, redux, themes, react-redux

The idea is to get a configuration JSON from the server after login. And depending on the config(let say a company the user is linked to) use one of the pre-set styles. The frontend is React-based. So, I'll not be able to get the main styles tag by id and change it on the fly:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="../green.css" id="theme_css" />

document.getElementById('theme_css').href = '../red.css';
```

Are there any other common ways to load files dynamicly in React(Redux) web-app?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. It works great for even larger projects of your browser support is slightly higher or you can implement the same with the help of SASS/LESS.

https://medium.com/@harishv6665_49536/theming-with-react-js-or-any-in-minutes-with-css-variables-11d4ebecdb41